# name of this atmospheric phenomenon: possible crepuscular ray?

Tags: sun, atmospheric-optics

This morning I took this picture pointing East, just before Sun rise (also the Moon and Venus are visible there): there's a tilted blue vertical ray amidst the golden horizon: I suppose this can be a crepuscular ray passing through a not yet visible cloud, but I'm wondering if this can be another phenomenon...

Unfortunately I could not wait to see if there was a cloud with the Sun when it rose. What I can say is that there were no clouds visible in the sky at that moment.

[image: possible crepuscular ray, pointing East before Sun rise]

Comment: For this kind of question, this website is a great resource: https://atoptics.co.uk/

Comment: Location is also of course always useful, though the availability of great satellite data may already be passing by

Comment: @JeopardyTempest : Are there so precise satellite data publicly available as to detect a single little cloud there?

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival : It's a great site indeed! but explanations are some times very brief, and I cannot interact to ask doubts ‍♀️

Comment: The current [US GOES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOES-16) has 0.5-2 km resolution, which does help pick up individual clouds, especially when they are types more often setalone like cumulus (which I believe are most often responsible for crepuscular-related things for example).  [See here currently for exampling](https://weather.cod.edu/satrad/?parms=local-Georgia-truecolor-24-1-100-1&checked=map-glm_flash&colorbar=undefined) (better in daytime)